# Bootstrap Collapse Navbar - Pulling Text Left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

So... When my Navbar is on a Desktop or Laptop screen I want the text to be pulled right which is what I have done, but when they are viewing my Website from a Phone I collapse the Navbar. When the Navbar is collapsed I would like the text to be pulled left instead of right I just can't find a way to do it.

I've tried text-align but obviously that only aligns the text whereas I want it being pull left when it is shown on a Phone screen.

```html
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Web Designs</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- /.End of Navbar -->
```

Comment: Please add the HTML/CSS you're using.

Comment: You should consider working from a 'mobile first' approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the pull-right class it actually floats the element to the right...So in order to make it appear on the left hand side on smaller devices you should target the desired device width and float it to the left, like this:

```
   @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .navbar-nav {
         float: left !important;
      }
   }
```

This should work for you :)

Comment: I didn't float it right I pull-right within the HTML code, would floating it right within a Media Query make it easier to pull the text left when collapsed?

Comment: I edited my previous answer for you, Hope you understand it now :)